# Separate hosts file for multiple ZAP daemon

Tags: unix, hosts, zap

I am starting multiple (for now let's assume 2) ZAP daemons on a server on different ports say 8080 and 9090. Now these 2 ZAP instances are given to 2 different users. Now if both user's are trying to access an application say www.myapp.com but on their own servers, where one app is hosted on 10.0.0.1 and other on 10.0.0.2.

Since ZAP is on one server, I need the ability to have 2 different hosts file for each ZAP, So that hosts mapping can be provided separately for ZAP.

Please provide a solution on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You could write 2 ZAP proxy scripts which replace www.myapp.com with the 2 different IP addresses.

There are various example scripts here: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/proxy

Comment: Hi @Psiinon, I cant replace the hostname with the IP. I need ZAP to resolve the hostname like a normal DNS Query, because at the application end, there is a check for hostname, thus the hostname needs to be in the request.

Comment: Would something like this do the trick? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts

Comment: Tried this already, this provides host aliases, not DNS resolution. So this, won't work. I found a solution to the problem, I'll be posting it as an answer.